# dosfsck seems to hang after bad cluster message

Tags: partitioning, badblocks

I used the following terminal command to fix bad sector on `/dev/sda5` partition I have which is FAT32

```
sudo dosfsck -w -r -l -a -v -t /dev/sda5
```

after running for a long time it displayed the following:

```
Cluster 3109747 is unreadable.
Cluster 3109748 is unreadable.
Cluster 3109749 is unreadable.
Cluster 3109750 is unreadable.
Cluster 3109751 is unreadable.
Cluster 3109752 is unreadable.
Cluster 3109753 is unreadable.
Cluster 3109754 is unreadable.
Cluster 3109755 is unreadable.
Cluster 3109756 is unreadable.
Cluster 3109758 is unreadable.
Cluster 3109759 is unreadable.
Cluster 3109760 is unreadable.
```

and there is a white blinking cursor at the end but it seems to be hangs because the white cusros keeps blinking without any other output.
what to do?

Answer (score 0):

> what to do?

Generally I would expect a hardware problem when a filesystem check locks up.

The only advice I can give is to try to repair it using Windows. Dos tools will be almost 100% compatible but there is never a guarantee. You might just have ran into a bug.

Besides that: open a 2nd terminal and see if any of the logs in /var/log/ is being written. If so there might be a notice there that explains there is a problem. If so add that to the question.

The other option is to throw it into the bin.